# VB6, RDO AND QUERYSTRING

Tags: vb6, query-string, rdo

I'm creating a query string as follows ...

`gSql = "{ CALL MYSP( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, {resultset 10, RECORD_OUTPUT} ) }"`

the `{resultset 1000, RECORD_OUTPUT}` is copied it from Microsoft's MSDN

The error displayed after I compile is:

> identifier \'RECORD_OUTPUT\' must be declared

What should the `{resultset 1000, RECORD_OUTPUT}` actually be ?

At this position, The Stored Procedure will return refcursor back to VB6.

Comment: Actually RDO was a short-lived VB5 technology supported in VB6 only for porting VB5 code forward until it could be rewritten.

Comment: I needed to develop my customer's code which is using RDO and I still got stucked into this ....

Comment: What MSDN page did you get this from?